# Use TBB to create a vector in parallel

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, tbb

I have a `vector<int> foo` and a function `float bar(int)`.  Using the `algorithms` library, I can populate a `vector<float> quux` with

```
transform(foo.begin(), foo.end(), quux.begin(), bar);
```

My `foo` function happens to be very slow and I was hoping to use the TBB library to parallelise this code across multiple threads.  I would have though that this would be an ideal case, since all the operations are independent.  However, there doesn't seem to be a `parallel_transform` algorithm.  Every example I've seen with the `parallel_for` algorithms puts the data back into the original array, which I can't do, since I'm changing the type.

Comment: Just initialise `quux` with the contents of `foo` and transform as normal.

Comment: While that would work in this specific case, it would fail for the reverse case of where foo is floats, quux is ints, and bar turns a float into an int.  I was wondering if there was a more general solution

Comment: std::transform has an overload for parallel execution. its in the standard library. it works fine on visual studio. i dont know about other compiler suites. maybe they lack support for this feature.

Comment: @phön Yes, that's a C++17 feature. Currently the support varies. GCC 9.1 supports it using TBB (so TBB needs be installed and linked for it to work).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a reference to the target to make it happen. Example code:

```
std::vector<float> quux(foo.size());
parallel_for(size_t(0), foo.size(), [&foo,&quux] (size_t i) {
    quux[i] = bar(foo[i]);
});
```